# C++ error: expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, gcc

I wrote a program in C++ couple of years ago and I use it quite a lot. This program uses a library called LTENSOR which I just use and I am not fully aware of everything happens there. 2 days ago after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 I installed the latest version of gcc compiler (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04). Now when I run the same program that I run for couple of years I get the following error:

> In file included from /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/ltensor/./base/Array_base.h:29:0,
>                    from /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/ltensor/LTensor.h:32,
>                    from /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/Soillab.cpp:14:
>   /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/ltensor/./base/../storage/storage.h: In member function ‘long int GenericStorage::getBeginAddress(int, int)’:
>   /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/ltensor/./base/../storage/storage.h:207:62: error: expression cannot be used as a function
>            gsize= (dim==0?0: stride(getPos(ordering,dim-1,rank) )) ;
>                                                                 ^
>   [Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: g++ "/home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/Soillab.cpp" -o "/home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab/Soillab"]
>   [dir: /home/alex/Documents/My Soilab/Soillab]
>   [path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]

It seems that it comes from the code bellow

```
long getBeginAddress(int offset,int dim){

    long gsize=0;
    gsize= (dim==0?0: stride(getPos(ordering,dim-1,rank) )) ;
    return gsize+offset;
    }
```

I cannot understand why I get this error. Thanks.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively determine the problem, but only guess, at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Instead of initializing to `0` and then immediately reassigning, why not `long gsize = ...` and just get it over with? Even better: Skip the variable and just return the calculation with `gsize` expanded.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will try to isolate this function and edit the question. It is not easy cause it is a part of a library that I have not written myself, but you are right I must try.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your answer. However, I get the same error message.

Comment: When you're up against a problem you don't understand, the first thing to try is cleaning up your code in the hopes that makes the error more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line

```
gsize= (dim==0?0: stride(getPos(ordering,dim-1,rank) )) ;
```

seems to originate from https://github.com/lromor/ltensor/blob/master/ltensor/storage/storage.h#L207

But on line #84, `stride` is declared as `long* stride`: https://github.com/lromor/ltensor/blob/master/ltensor/storage/storage.h#L84

So `stride` is a pointer, not a function.